# Is GSM data sending between 2 phones impossible?

Tags: communication, gsm, mobile-phones

Please tell me in detail why it is impossible to send the data between two phones over GSM? I can find almost no information about this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 2 points here.

Firstly, GSM is a mobile voice telephony system - plain GSM doesn't do data connections.
GPRS and EDGE are add-ons to the GSM network that allow data to be sent.
There are other kinds of wireless phone networks that also use a SIM and allow data to be sent (UMTS, LTE).

Secondly, when you establish a data connection with a mobile phone and a phone network, you are establishing an IP connection between your phone/modem and a gateway server in the operator's network.  The gateway server allows you access to the internet (together with the DNS server etc, obviously).

This is similar to a computer plugging in a LAN cable and connecting to their ISP.  But you can also connect 2 computers with a crossover cable, and configure them to have an IP connection directly.  So what you are asking is, why can't I do the same with 2 GSM phones?  what is the equivalent of a wireless crossover cable?

The reason is because GSM has no protocol to connect phones to each other.  It only defines a protocol for phones to connect to a network base station.

To transfer data between 2 phones, therefore, you need a different protocol, one which will work between 2 peers.  Bluetooth is a common such protocol, but it only works over short distances.
If you want to connect 2 distant phones, you can do this via a third party, like a website, to which data can be uploaded into the cloud by the first phone and downloaded by the second phone.
Or, you could establish a connection at the IP level via the internet, e.g. if one mobile device was a web server (the last sentence is only theorising).

See also this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834607/is-it-possible-to-build-peer-to-peer-gsm-connection-using-openbts)

EDIT: 3GPP Release 12 includes direct Device to Device communications.  At the time of writing, it's still very new, and not yet commercially available, so the answer above still holds.  D2D is designed for emergency services, eg if the network is damaged by a disaster, they can still communicate directly.  But 3GPP suggests that it will be commercially available as well.  From [3GPP news](http://www.3gpp.org/news-events/3gpp-news/1614-sa_5g)

> There are also commercial benefits of D2D, with new applications building on the physical proximity of users being trialed by operators.

2nd EDIT: Apple has created a feature called [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html), which uses a mixture of WiFi networks, peer-to-peer WiFi and Bluetooth to enable short distance connectivity between iPhones when there is no GSM network.

NFC is another peer-to-peer technology for communicating between 2 devices, that is supported by some phones.  More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nfc/info).

Comment: As far as I understand, I need to write my own communication protocol, which solves the problem of phone IP distribution. Thanks!

Comment: Not just protocol, you would need hardware support to transmit and receive the signals on the wavelength that you chose.  GSM phones transmit and receive on specified GSM bands.

Comment: Actually GSM does support data connections using [Circuit Switched Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_Switched_Data).

Comment: Very slow and not available in most networks.